# Python groupby dates but with if statement

Tags: python, pandas

My data looks like this:

```
id   Open    Close
1    1/1/15   1/1/15 
2    1/1/15   2/1/15
3    3/1/15   4/1/15
```

I need to create a dataframe that shows the number of open cases on any day, so the result of the data above would look like:

```
Date   #Open
1/1/15   1
2/1/15   0
3/1/15   1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think `open` is in `3/1/15` equal `1` and is missing `4/1/15` with `1` too.

Comment: shouldn't the count for `1/1/15` be 1? At end of the day, one event got closed?

Comment: updated data to satisfy a date<closed, instead of a <=closed

Answer (score 1):

This method creates an index of all days between the first case open and the max of the last case opened or closed.  It then iterates through each of these dates and filters the dataframe for the relevant date, checking the resulting size.

```
df['Open'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Open)
df['Close'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Close)

idx = pd.date_range(df.Open.min(), max(df.Open.max(), df.Close.max()))

cases = pd.DataFrame([len(df[(date >= df.Open) & (date < df.Close)]) 
                      for date in idx], 
                     index=idx, columns=['case_count'])

>>> cases.head(3)
            case_count
2015-01-01           1
2015-01-02           1
2015-01-03           1

>>> cases.tail(3)
            case_count
2015-03-30           1
2015-03-31           1
2015-04-01           0
```